# React-Redux update recursive Component property

Tags: javascript, recursion, reactjs, redux

I have a state tree of objects, these objects get rendered recursively.

- Object
- Object

  - Object
  - Object
  - **Object**

    - Object
    - Object

The bolded object is a recursively rendered react Component, when a button in this component is clicked a value from this component should be updated.

What would be the most efficient way to find the object in bold in the state tree when I want to update it? Do I generate a unique key for each object and then use a for loop to update the object with that certain key? How would I generate a unique key?

Do I import Immutable.js and use one of those functions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the shape of your state tree? It is almost always easier to keep the state tree as flat as possible and use ids to define relationships. When clicking on a component, just pass along the id of the object that was clicked. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/tree-view might be helpful

Comment: I have an object that contains a name, type and an array of objects of the same type, that can contain another array of objects of the same type, ... These objects do not have an ID, so I would have to generate one.

Comment: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr is a library you can use for this purpose. This might also be of use https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4416ea/redux_app_state_deep_or_flat/

Comment: How would I go about generating an unique Id, just store it in the state and increment it every time I need it?

Comment: I'd do it on bootup of the app before you pass the data into redux. Ids just need to be unique among your objects. Incrementing a number will work, or you can use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid to generate ids.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the help. I'll have to take a good look at the tree-view example and normalizer to determine which approach to take.